# Is there a way to do a like button using the facebook sdk in unity/android?:

Tags: android, facebook-like, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have searched everywhere and can not find anything about using the facebook sdk for unity/android to do a like button.

Is this feature not available yet?  Or am I blind?

Comment: For future readers: Looks like you could do something with FB.Feed(), if I get some actual code I'll post an answer, working on same thing myself right now. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed

Comment: @eselk   did you find solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There's no native SDK support for the like button, but you can try this code that integrate the function:
https://github.com/crowjdh/android-facebook-like-button-integration

Comment: When I have eclipse installed the android build options for unity are broken.

Answer (score 0):

The following Link should help you, [Official Facebook Doku](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes)
[EDIT]
In the above Link you find an explanation of how you should "Post" a Like.
Also in the following Link you find all permissions, with `user_likes` in `FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions()` also `FB.LogInWithReadPermissions` you should be able to Post likes and somehow read them: [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)